# JS regular expression engine - recursion w/ limited number of levels

Tags: javascript, regex

### Using: JavaScript regular expressions

https://regex101.com/r/bWkBpD/2

```
function {
  if () {
    if {}
  }
}

// I do not want to match this (only 3 level nesting not 4):

function {
  if () {
    if {
      if {}
    }
  }
}
```

I know JavaScript regular expression engine does not includes **balancing groups**, **recursion** or whatever. This is reason why I need a limited number of levels.

#### What I have to match (only 3 level nesting):

```
function {
  if () {
    if {}
  }
}
```

Comment: What about cases like `if (s.Contains("{{{{")) {`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew u are right (damn)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Is something like that possible in JS w/ built in RegExp-s?

Comment: Sorry, at this time, the question is too broad. In general, this kind of thing is solved with dedicated language syntax parsers.